# What effect does Gary Fong's collapsible LightSphere have on color temperature?

Tags: lighting, white-balance, lighting-modifiers

I intend to use a Gary Fong collapsible LightSphere, the one with white-transparent body and the warmer yellow semi-sphere for shooting portraits on locations and studio.

1. How can I know the real color temperature of this product?
2. The mixing of the filtered speedlight flash light (transparent-white and yellow) will be treated as a mixed color temperature?
3. How can I achieve "natural feeling results" of the images (For example in a sunset portrait or in a night bonfire portrait).
4. Is this product to be consider as an example of mixed temperature lighting?
5. Taking the example of Gary Fong collapsible LightSphere it is possible to make other complex mixing illuminations designs.  For this kind of situation (in photography) is it useful to have a spectrometer?